# How to write a trigger that updates a table based on the action taken in another table?

Tags: sql, database, triggers, db2

I have a table named `ORDERITEMS`.

```
CREATE TABLE DB2ADMIN.ORDERITEMS (
  ORDERITEMS_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL,
  STOREENT_ID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ORDERS_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL,
  TERMCOND_ID   BIGINT,
  TRADING_ID    BIGINT,
  ITEMSPC_ID    BIGINT,
  CATENTRY_ID   BIGINT,
  PARTNUM   VARCHAR(64)
);
```

I need to create a new table named `ORDERITEM_LOG` that looks basically the same, but with two additional columns:

```
CREATE TABLE DB2ADMIN.ORDERITEM_LOG (
  ORDERITEMS_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL,
  STOREENT_ID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ORDERS_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL,
  TERMCOND_ID   BIGINT,
  TRADING_ID    BIGINT,
  ITEMSPC_ID    BIGINT,
  CATENTRY_ID   BIGINT,
  PARTNUM   VARCHAR(64),
  LOG_ACTION_DATE VARCHAR(254),
  LOG_ACTION_TYPE VARCHAR(1)
);
```

I need to make a trigger that watches the `ORDERITEMS` table.  Whenever a row is inserted, deleted, or updated in the `ORDERITEMS` table, the identical operation needs to be done to the `ORDERITEM_LOG` table, with the additional two columns being populated with `CURRENT TIMESTAMP`, and a `'U'`, `'D'`, or `'I'` (depending on the action taken), respectively.

For example, if I insert a row into the `ORDERITEMS` table, I would expect to see a duplicate row inserted into the `ORDERITEM_LOG` table, timestamped in `LOG_ACTION_DATE`, and an `'I'` in the `LOG_ACTION_TYPE`.  Then, if I were to delete the row in `ORDERITEMS`, I would expect to see the `'I'` updated to a `'D'` in the `ORDERITEM_LOG` table, and see the timestamp updated.  I'm looking to have the `ORDERITEM_LOG` table updated **before** the `ORDERITEMS` table;

How do I write a trigger that would do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Have you looked at the trigger examples in the manual? Have you tried writing some code? Is there anything in particular that you're struggling with?

Comment: Yeah I've tried writing some code for an insert only, but I'm not really sure where to go.  CREATE TRIGGER OI_LOG_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON ORDERITEMS 
FOR EACH FOR
BEGIN
 ??? INSERT INTO ORDERITEM_LOG () VALUES ();??? --not sure what goes here
END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Types of Triggers
     There are two types of Triggers. After and Instead of Triggers. you have to use After triggers

1)After Triggers

These triggers are executed after an action such as Insert, Update or Delete is performed.

you have to use after trigger like below

**After Insert**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Customer_INSERT]
   ON [dbo].[Customers]
   AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE @OrderItemsID;
  DECLARE @StroreentID;
   DECLARE @OrdersID;
   DECLARE @TermCondID;
   DECLARE @TradingID ;
   DECLARE @ItemSPCID;
   DECLARE @CatentryID;
   DECLARE @Partnum;  
   DECLARE @SysDateTime datetime = SYSDATETIME();
   DECLARE @LogActionType VARCHAR(1);

   SELECT @OrderItemsID = INSERTED.ORDERITEMS_ID;
   SELECT @StroreentID = INSERTED.STOREENT_ID;
   SELECT @OrdersID = INSERTED.ORDERS_ID;
   SELECT @TermCondID = INSERTED.TERMCOND_ID;
   SELECT @TradingID = INSERTED.TRADING_ID;
   SELECT @ItemSPCID = INSERTED.ITEMSPC_ID;
   SELECT @CatentryID = INSERTED.CATENTRY_ID;
   SELECT @Partnum = INSERTED.PARTNUM;

   @LogActionType = "1";

   FROM INSERTED

   INSERT INTO ORDERITEM_LOG
   VALUES (@OrderItemsID, @StroreentID, @OrdersID, @TermCondID, @TradingID, @ItemSPCID, @CatentryID, Partnum, LogActionType, @LogActionType)
END
```

**After Update**

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Customer_INSERT]
   ON [dbo].[Customers]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE @OrderItemsID;
  DECLARE @StroreentID;
   DECLARE @OrdersID;
   DECLARE @TermCondID;
   DECLARE @TradingID ;
   DECLARE @ItemSPCID;
   DECLARE @CatentryID;
   DECLARE @Partnum;  
   DECLARE @SysDateTime datetime = SYSDATETIME();
   DECLARE @LogActionType VARCHAR(1);

   SELECT @OrderItemsID = INSERTED.ORDERITEMS_ID;
   SELECT @StroreentID = INSERTED.STOREENT_ID;
   SELECT @OrdersID = INSERTED.ORDERS_ID;
   SELECT @TermCondID = INSERTED.TERMCOND_ID;
   SELECT @TradingID = INSERTED.TRADING_ID;
   SELECT @ItemSPCID = INSERTED.ITEMSPC_ID;
   SELECT @CatentryID = INSERTED.CATENTRY_ID;
   SELECT @Partnum = INSERTED.PARTNUM;

   @LogActionType = "1";

   FROM INSERTED

   INSERT INTO ORDERITEM_LOG
   VALUES(@OrderItemsID, @StroreentID,@OrdersID,@TermCondID,@TradingID,@ItemSPCID,@CatentryID,Partnum,LogActionType, @LogActionType)
END
```

**After DELETE**

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Customer_INSERT]
   ON [dbo].[Customers]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE @OrderItemsID;
   DECLARE @StroreentID;
   DECLARE @OrdersID;
   DECLARE @TermCondID;
   DECLARE @TradingID ;
   DECLARE @ItemSPCID;
   DECLARE @CatentryID;
   DECLARE @Partnum;  
   DECLARE @SysDateTime datetime = SYSDATETIME();
   DECLARE @LogActionType VARCHAR(1);

   SET @LogActionType = "1";
   SELECT @OrderItemsID = DELETED.ORDERITEMS_ID;
   SELECT @StroreentID = DELETED.STOREENT_ID;
   SELECT @OrdersID = DELETED.ORDERS_ID;
   SELECT @TermCondID = DELETED.TERMCOND_ID;
   SELECT @TradingID = DELETED.TRADING_ID;
   SELECT @ItemSPCID = DELETED.ITEMSPC_ID;
   SELECT @CatentryID = DELETED.CATENTRY_ID;
   SELECT @Partnum = DELETED.PARTNUM;


   INSERT INTO ORDERITEM_LOG
   VALUES(@OrderItemsID, @StroreentID,@OrdersID,@TermCondID,@TradingID,@ItemSPCID,@CatentryID,Partnum,LogActionType, @LogActionType)
END
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you want to snapshot your changes to table2. Good tactic by the time amount of data will create you a big headache. The sql code you need as below. You may create one trigger for all jobs with tag INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE or you may create seperate 3 triggers. Just pay attention that SQL UPDATE command triggers delete and insert statement in same time.

Below example is using BulkInsert and assume that you log tables exists. If you are updating a few rows at a time there is no problem,but if you are manipulating so many rows at same time probably you will timeout or have so long response time. To prevent that you may prefer to write same statement with where clause targeting primary key ( as where id=XXX) within a WHILE statement.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [ORDERITEMTRIGGER] ON [ORDERITEMS] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
-- INSERT
set nocount on
insert into ORDERITEM_LOG(
  ORDERITEMS_ID,
  STOREENT_ID,
  ORDERS_ID,
  TERMCOND_ID,
  TRADING_ID,
  ITEMSPC_ID,
  CATENTRY_ID,
  PARTNUM,
  LOG_ACTION_DATE,
  LOG_ACTION_TYPE)
select   ORDERITEMS_ID,
  STOREENT_ID,
  ORDERS_ID,
  TERMCOND_ID,
  TRADING_ID,
  ITEMSPC_ID,
  CATENTRY_ID,
  PARTNUM,
  getdate(),'I' from inserted

-- DELETE (this triggers on delete and update because sql update has 2 phase delete and insert)
insert into ORDERITEM_LOG(
  ORDERITEMS_ID,
  STOREENT_ID,
  ORDERS_ID,
  TERMCOND_ID,
  TRADING_ID,
  ITEMSPC_ID,
  CATENTRY_ID,
  PARTNUM,
  LOG_ACTION_DATE,
  LOG_ACTION_TYPE)
select   ORDERITEMS_ID,
  STOREENT_ID,
  ORDERS_ID,
  TERMCOND_ID,
  TRADING_ID,
  ITEMSPC_ID,
  CATENTRY_ID,
  PARTNUM,
  getdate(),'D' from deleted

-- UPDATE
set nocount on
insert into ORDERITEM_LOG(
  ORDERITEMS_ID,
  STOREENT_ID,
  ORDERS_ID,
  TERMCOND_ID,
  TRADING_ID,
  ITEMSPC_ID,
  CATENTRY_ID,
  PARTNUM,
  LOG_ACTION_DATE,
  LOG_ACTION_TYPE)
select   ORDERITEMS_ID,
  STOREENT_ID,
  ORDERS_ID,
  TERMCOND_ID,
  TRADING_ID,
  ITEMSPC_ID,
  CATENTRY_ID,
  PARTNUM,
  getdate(),'U' from inserted
set nocount off
```